# apache2 start server with graphite

Tags: apache2, postgresql, graphite

I have installed all I need in order to use Graphite and Graphana

- Ipdated system
- install SW (`apt-get install build-essential graphite-web graphite-carbon python-dev apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi libpq-dev python-psycopg2`)
- Configure Carbon
- Install and Configure PostgreSQL
- Configure Graphite (`user: graphite, on localhost, engine: django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` )
- On Apache for Graphite step:
  I added `<VirtualHost *:8080>` on `/etc/apache2/sites-available/apache2-graphite.conf`
  and added `Listen 8080` on `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`
  also:
  `a2dissite 000-default`
  `a2ensite apache2-graphite`
  `service apache2 reload`

with *sudo* previleges.

The problem is that when I go to the web browser (localhost:8080) it gives me an error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error
log.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 8080
```

this should be the Graphite web interface, but it's not working.
Apache, carbon, postgres are running.

any idea?

Comment: It's really hard to say something by using only information above. Please show us what's in your Apache's `error.log`

Answer (score 0):

Two error logs you want to check out are:

- /var/log/apache2/error.log
- /var/log/apache2/graphite-web_error.log    {more useful}

I've found a few reasons that can cause this error screen to get produced. In my case I'm seeing errors with the "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" file.